# Changing chars in char pointer variable

Tags: c, pointers

I am trying to change chars pointed to by a char pointer variable:

```
    char *test3 = "mutable";
    printf("Expected: mutable, Result: %s\n", test3);
    testt(test3);
    printf("Expected tutable, Result: %s\n", test3);

    void testt(char *s) {
        *s = 't'; // FAILS, I get Segmentation Fault Error
    }
```

Why does the above approach not work? Are chars pointed to by pointer variables immutable? If so, how would I modify the contents of the pointer variable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is because your `char *` points to a string literal and string literals are in almost every modern OS located in read-only storage.

Try copying it onto the stack:

```
char test3[] = "mutable";
```