# How to assign value to a pointer

Tags: c, pointers, segmentation-fault

I have a char pointer and i give it a value. In a next step i want to change the first letter.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void main() {
    char * str;
    str = (char*)malloc(4);
    str = "abc";
    printf("%s\n", str); //output: abc
    *str = 'c';          //segmentation fault
    printf("%s\n", str); //here i would like to have output cbc
}
```

Why does it not work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

when you assign  "abc" to str, it doesn't copy "abc" to the newly allocated memory. Instead str now points to readonly memory where the constant "abc" is stored.

You get a segmentation fault because you try to write to read-only memory.

instead of

```
str = "abc";
```

try

```
str[0] = 'a';
str[1] = 'b';
str[2] = 'c';
str[3] = '\0';
```

Comment: Ok. I'll use arrays instead of pointers. Thanks.

Comment: Now i found this answer also:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22103212/changing-chars-in-char-pointer-variable?rq=1

Answer (score 2):

There are few issues in the code. Firstly, here

```
str = (char*)malloc(4); /* dynamic memory i.e str points to heap section */
str = "abc"; /* str now points to ready only memory i.e string constants */
```

you are overwriting dynamically allocated memory with string literal `"abc"` memory i.e its a memory leak as `str` no longer points to dynamic memory.

To avoid all these issues either create a local character array, not dynamic one and then change the `str[0]`. For e.g

```
char str[4] = "abc";
*str = 'c';
```

Or use `memcpy()` if you want to do first `mallco()` and then copey `abc` into that. For e.g

```
int main(void) {
    char *str = malloc(4); /* Don't use magic number like 4, use MACRO instead */
    if(str == NULL) {
        /* @TODO Error Handling of malloc failure */
    }
    memcpy(str, "abc",sizeof("abc"));
    printf("%s\n", str); 
    *str = 'c';          
    printf("%s\n", str); 
    /* free dynamic memory */
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> How to assign value to a pointer?

With one of the assignment operators, of course.  Typically the simple assignment operator (`=`), but plussignment (`+=`) and minussignment (`-=`) can also be used under some circumstances.

> I have a char pointer and i give it a value.

In fact, you give it *two different values*, one after the other.  First, with

> ```
>     str = (char*)malloc(4);
> ```

you give it a value that points to your four-byte dynamically allocated space.  Note that the cast is unnecessary in C and considered poor style by many.

Then, with

> ```
>    str = "abc";
> ```

, you assign it a different value, losing the previous one and therefore leaking memory.  You are assigning a value *to the pointer*, not modifying the data to which it points.

You have several alternatives for modifying the pointed-to memory.

- You can assign directly via the pointer and related ones (not forgetting the string terrminator!):

  ```
  *str = 'a';
  *(str + 1) = 'b';
  // etc.
  ```
- Equivalently to the previous, you can use indexing syntax

  ```
  str[0] = 'a';
  str[1] = 'b';
  // etc.
  ```
- You can perform a block copy with the `memcpy()` or `memmove()` function:

  ```
  memcpy(str, "abc", 4);
  ```
- For C strings in particular, such as yours, there are functions specific to this purpose, the common being `strcpy()`:

  ```
  strcpy(str, "abc");
  ```

  Note that `strcpy` expects the source to be null terminated, which all string literals are, but some other character arrays are not.

> In a next step i want to change the first letter.

Your syntax is correct for that, but you may not modify a string literal. That's what your original code is trying to do, because that's your second assignment causes `str` to point to the literal `"abc"`.

Overall, **do not confuse a pointer with the object to which it points**.